# Show $ F^{\prime}\left(t_{0}\right)=D f_{p+t_{0} v}(v)=D_{v} f\left(p+t_{0} v\right) $

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

- Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is differentiable and given $p, v \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ define $F(t)=f(p+t v)$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that for
  all $t_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
  $$
  F^{\prime}\left(t_{0}\right)=D f_{p+t_{0} v}(v)=D_{v} f\left(p+t_{0} v\right)
  $$

My attempt. $F^{\prime}\left(t_{0}\right)=f'(p+t_0v)$,

$D_{v} f\left(p+t_{0} v\right)=\lim_{t\to 0} \dfrac {f(p+t_0v+tu)-f(p+t_0v)} {t},$

What is the $D f_{p+t_{0} v}(v)$?

And how can I show that equality?
$$
F^{\prime}\left(t_{0}\right)=D f_{p+t_{0} v}(v)=D_{v} f\left(p+t_{0} v\right)
$$

May you help? Thanks...

Comment: Do you know the change rule?

Comment: @hal4math I don't know

Comment: Maybe you should check [it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Multivariable_case) out.

Comment: @hal4math I will check, but can you say what is the $D f_{p+t_{0} v}(v)$?

Comment: @hal4math I couldn't understand this notation

Comment: @hal4math You said ''change rule'', but your link is ''chain rule''???

Comment: Ups, sorry, I miss-wrote. $Df_{p+t_0v}(v)$ means you are evaluating the total derivative at the point $p+t_0v$ and then evaluate this linear map on $v$.

Comment: @hal4math how can I use chain rule in this question?

Comment: $F'(t_0) = (f(p +t_0 v))' = (Df(p +t_0v))\circ (p+t_0v)' = (Df(p +t_0v))(v)$.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically showing how the Frechet and Gateaux derivatives are related: first, write $F$ as a composition $F=f\circ g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^n$ where $g(t)=p+tv$. Now then, by the chain rule:

$\tag1 DF(t_0)=Df(g(t_0))((Dg(t_0))=Df(g(t_0))v$

But, $Df(g(t_0))$ is the linear transformation: $\mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^n$ that satisfies

$\tag2 f(g(t_0)+u)=f(g(t_0))+Df(g(t_0))u+r(u)$

where $\frac{r(u)}{|u|}\to 0$ as $|u|\to 0$ so putting this together, with $u=tv$, we get

$\tag3 \frac{f(g(t_0)+tv)-f(g(t_0))}{t}=Df(g(t_0))v+\frac{r(tv)} {t}=Df(g(t_0))v+\frac{r(tv)}{t|v|}|v|$

Letting $t\to 0$, we get

$\tag4 D_{v} f\left(p+t_{0} v\right)=\underset{t\to 0}\lim \frac{f(g(t_0)+tv)-f(g(t_0))}{t}=Df(g(t_0))v=DF(t_0)$